# A question on analytical geometry.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The diagonals of a rectangular are along $y+7x-6=0$ and $ y-7x+5=0$. If the area of the rectangle is 8, then find the vertices of the rectangle.

I found the baricentre of the rectangle which is $(\frac{11}{14},\frac{1}{2})$ and then tried finding the diagonal length but it only got more complicated. Please help me.

Comment: It is 14 instead of 24

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima sorry. Typing mistake. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slopes of the two diagonals are $7$ and $-7$ respectively. So the horizontal side and the vertical side of the rectangle are in the ratio of $1:7$. If the horizontal side is $2k$, then the vertical side is $14k$ and

$$(2k)(14k)=8$$

So $k=\frac{\sqrt{14}}{7}$.

The four vertices are $\displaystyle \left(\frac{11}{14}+\frac{\sqrt{14}}{7},\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{14}\right)$, $\displaystyle \left(\frac{11}{14}+\frac{\sqrt{14}}{7},\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{14}\right)$, $\displaystyle \left(\frac{11}{14}-\frac{\sqrt{14}}{7},\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{14}\right)$ and $\displaystyle \left(\frac{11}{14}-\frac{\sqrt{14}}{7},\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{14}\right)$.

[image]

Comment: Just one last question, how did u get that ratio 1:7

Comment: I included a picture to my solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Umm.... Sorry for bothering this much.... But I still don't get how u got that ratio

Comment: By symmetry, the sides of the rectangle are parallel to the coordinate axes. The slope is equal to the vertical increment divided by the horizontal increment. The slope of a diagonal is $7$ implies that the vertical side is $7$ times the horizontal side.

Comment: Oh thank u. Helped a lot

Comment: @LokeshSangewar I got same result without Cinema.

Comment: How did u write that the vertices are those? I mean is it a formula? If yes, can you please give a proof?

Comment: I think I=2√14/7

Comment: starting from the centre, we just move half the lengths of the sides horizontally and vertically. The length of the horizontal side is $2k=\frac{2\sqrt{14}}{7}$, but we just move $k=\frac{\sqrt{14}}{7}$ horizontally from the centre.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to see that $M\left(\frac{11}{14},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is a center of the rectangle $ABCD$.

Let $\alpha$ is an angle between diagonals. Thus,

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{14}{49-1}=\frac{7}{24}$$
Hence, since $1+\cot^2\alpha=\frac{1}{\sin^2\alpha}$, we obtain:
$$1+\frac{576}{49}=\frac{1}{\sin^2\alpha},$$
which gives $\sin\alpha=\frac{7}{25}$.

Now, $S_{\Delta AMB}=\frac{1}{4}S_{ABCD}=2$.

Thus, $\frac{1}{2}AM^2\sin\alpha=2$, which gives $AM=\frac{10}{\sqrt7}$.

Now, let $y=7x-5$ is an equation of $AC$ and $y=-7x+6$ is an equation of $BD$.

Thus, for the vertexes $A$ and $C$ we get the following equation:
$$\left(x-\frac{11}{14}\right)^2+\left(7x-5-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{100}{7}$$ or
$$(14x-11)^2=56,$$
which gives very ugly numbers.

The equation for the vertexes $B$ and $D$ is
$$\left(x-\frac{11}{14}\right)^2+\left(-7x+6-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{100}{7},$$ 
which is similar.

Comment: Can u please explain in detail how u got tan A and what is S∆AMB? Because I don't want to copy the answer blindly. Please

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar $S_{\Delta AMB}$ is an area of $\Delta AMB$. Let $m$ and $n$ are slopes of the diagonals. Thus, $\tan\alpha=\left|\frac{m-n}{1+mn}\right|$.

Comment: It would have been very helpful if u would have explained your answer with a figure. Can u please do it?

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar Draw rectangle $ABCD$ and take $M$ is a common point of $AC$ and $BD$. I am ready to post a full solution if you wish.

Comment: a full solution will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

** just a hint**

Let $a=11/14,$

$b=1/2$,

length $=2L,$

width $=2l .$

and  area=$4Ll=8.$

the vetrices will have coordinates
$$(a-L,b-l),(a-L,b+l),(a+L,b-l),(a+L,b+l) .$$

$(a-L,b-l) $ is in the line $:y-7x+5=0$ thus

$$b-l-7 (a-L)+5=0$$
or

$$1/2-2/L-11/2+7L+5=0$$
$$\implies L^2=2/7$$

$$\implies l^2=4/L^2=14$$

Comment: It's a=11/14 right?

Comment: How can u tell that the vertices will have those particular coordinates?

Comment: I am now greatly confused. How can we find L and l? 

Comment: Can u give me a proof or a link to the proof on how u got that particular coordinates please?

Comment: How? I mean you never wrote why you got (a-L,b-l)

Comment: Ok ok. No need of proof. Thanks a lot. I understood. ^_^